# Weird scp behavior

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to scp a file but it returns immediately with the DATE and not file is copied:

```
[cosmo] Downloads > scp V17530-01_1of2.zip bryan@elphaba:Downloads
bryan@elphaba's password:
Sat Apr 10 13:35:41 PDT 2010
```

I have never seen this before.  I have confirmed that I have the sshd running on the target system and that the firewall is allowing 22/tcp.

Any help on what is going on would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 4):

It is probably something in a login script (.bashrc, .profile, .login, .cshrc, .tcshrc, etc. depending on your shell).  Try `ssh elphaba ls Downloads` to see if anything is shown other than the directory listing.  Extraneous non-protocol output will be interpreted by scp as an error message and will just be displayed to the user.

For more details: http://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works#talkative_profiles